# How to delete MySQL record automatically after a specified time if not updated?

Tags: mysql

I would like to be able to have a MySQL record automatically deleted after 60 minutes if one of its columns hasn't been updated to a certain value within that period.  I can set up cron jobs in my hosting, but I'd prefer to have more granular or exact (time-specific) control over the timing.  I can't think of what would constitute the trigger (other than a cron job).  Is it actually possible?

Comment: Are you looking for [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html)?

Comment: "an object whose statements are executed in response to the passage of a specified time interval" - that looks exactly like what I'm looking for.  Gulp.  Maybe complicated eek but I'll give it a shot.  Many thanks!

Comment: Will your host allow you set up events? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html

Comment: I will enquire.  Thanks

Comment: No, I can't, unless I shell out for a private server.  Oh well, thanks for what I take to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could design your application/cron-job to schedule deletion of rows when they become close to expiry, so that they delete at that specific time. You would need to double check the row is still eligible for deletion at that time just before deleting it, in case it has been updated since.

Comment: Thank you.  I know that's possible with a cron job.  Just that I wanted to zap the row if not updated exactly one hour after it was created.  Cron jobs, even every minute, don't quite do this.  I can't schedule dynamic cron jobs in my hosting, if that's what you meant.

Comment: There is an `at` command that you can call from the cron job, which will run a script at a specific time (not sure if that's what you mean by a dynamic cron job)

Comment: Interesting.  But the `at` would have to be tied to each DB row, which, even if possible, would mean an insane number of cron jobs?  And probably not possible with my hosting..

Comment: Pretty much, so not ideal if you have a lot of rows. You could make the cron jobs more long-running. So, schedule a job every 15 minutes and keep it running in a loop, scanning the table and deleting any expired rows.